# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80640012

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi, wifi-direct

I am trying to listen connectionRequested listener,

```
private WiFiDirectConnectionListener _listener;
...
_listener.ConnectionRequested += ConnectionRequestedAsync;
```

Here is the listener callback,

```
private async void ConnectionRequestedAsync(WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender, WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs args) 
{
        WiFiDirectConnectionRequest request = args.GetConnectionRequest();
        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WiFiDirectDevice _device = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(request.DeviceInformation.Id);
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception::\"{0}\"", e.Message));
            }
        }
}
```

Exception found in log (for call `WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync`),

> Exception::"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80640012"

**Any Idea what can be the cause?**

Comment: Is error number that you posted correct?

Comment: @jdweng yes. I have double checked. Googled with the error code even before posting but no luck.

Comment: I always find the error number when searching. Can't find this number which is very unusual.

Comment: I would search the source code from GITHUB and see if you can find the error string.

Comment: @jdweng I always do that too.

Comment: I've found that error messages starting with 0x8 are usually invalid memory address.  So I would check the variable request.DeviceInformation.Id to see if it is valid.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem, however, `FromIdAsync` needs to be called from the UI thread, could you try to call it with disaptcher ?

Comment: @Nico I will try and let you know.

Comment: Good, thanks for your feed back.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT could you please tell me how to call this code in UI thread?

Comment: Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT as I am not creating any task, that piece of code already should be in the UI thread. right?

Comment: It's hard to say, but you could use   `var res = Window.Current.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess;` to check if current thread is [uithread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher?view=winrt-19041).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT `var res = Window.Current.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess;` call got NullReferenceException.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229078/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sazzad-hissain-khan).

Comment: it's strange, above code could work in my side.

Comment: could share which object is  null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me,

```
try
{
    // IMPORTANT: FromIdAsync needs to be called from the UI thread
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        _wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceID);
    }
    else
    {
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(async () =>
        {
            _wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceID);
        }));
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.E($"Exception in FromIdAsync: {ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}\n\r");
}
```